# What is the rule in Turkish called where /e/ becomes [æ] when preceding a syllable final nasal or liquid consonant?

Tags: phonology, turkish

Examples of these are words like

"sen" [sæn] vs [se̞n] (you)

"sel" [sæl] vs [se̞l] (flood)

where the latter realizations sound less natural to the average Istanbul Turkish speaker.

What is the name of this rule?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In his thesis (Hacattepe U), Börtlü call this rule "laxing" (p. 88). This is because he uses different IPA symbols, [e] for the general allophone and [ɛ] for the lowered or laxed allophone. You could get a corpus of formant measurements from the Turkish data file at [Ahn & Chodroff](https://osf.io/t957v/), possibly [here](https://osf.io/t957v/files/osfstorage/61d6f31372da2312fcbf943b) and [here](https://osf.io/t957v/files/osfstorage/61d6f313da6320114dfe6950) but these are dynamic URLs).